# retrieve over 3k records from external database from android Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, android, yii

Good morning to all... I'm struggling to find a way to retrieve over 3k of records from a database, what I'm actually doing is an HTTP Client request so my web service answer via POST, it answer with an array with the info I need, my web service is implemented with YII and it looks like this...

```
public function actionDownloadUnits() {
        $unitArray = array();
        if (isset($_POST['CustomerId'])) {
            $OwnerId = $_POST['CustomerId'];
            $model = Unit::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('OwnerId' => $OwnerId));
            foreach ($model as $row) {
                array_push($unitArray, "$row->Id,$row->SerialNumber");
            }
            echo implode("/", $unitArray);
        }
    }
```

I've implemented this kind of method several times and theres no problem when you fetch like 50 records but when you have a lot it takes a lot of time...

what I get as an answer is this message:

```
 Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded
```

What I want to know is if somebody can give me an example or a link to use a different protocol of communication or any other way to achieve this without exceeding the excecution time.

Answer (score 0):

You can raise the [max execution time](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-time-limit.php) or set it to -1 for unlimited time (not recommended).

However it would be better to store these record in the local database for much faster access.

**Edit:** You can setup a cronjob to start a php script, which runs every hour or less. The script transfers only the new data from remote db to your local db. Set the time limit to unlimited in your transfer script and you should be ok. You can set a shorter cronjob runtime or even start multiple transfer scripts.

Comment: yes that's what I want to do, once I get the array from my web service, I will store the answer in my internal DB but I need to check that information at least one time per session, increase the execution time is not an optiob in my case... but thanks for the reply

Comment: well thanks I figure it out... the model has a lot of relations so when I want to retrieve the rows it trys to pull also the relation records I achieve that by aplying unsetAttributes($model)